# Picasso is using data for cached images in an appwidget

Tags: android, caching, picasso, okhttp

We have an appwidget that contains multiple ImageViews that need to be updated with an image every once in a while. The images are stored on the web and the url's are stored in an ArrayList that we rotate through. We're using Picasso with an OkHttp3 Downloader that has a cache. Even after all images have been shown at least once our app is still using data according to the Android build in data usage option in the settings app. When turning on airplane mode the widget continues to work and shows all images so they have to be cached. Why is Picasso still using data even though the images are cached? (we've already ruled out all other possible sources of data consumption by the app/widget)

Libraries used:

- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0
- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
- com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0

Picasso initialization in Application Object onCreate():

```
    Picasso.Builder picassoBuilder = new Picasso.Builder(this)
        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(this))
        .indicatorsEnabled(true)
        .loggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso picasso = picassoBuilder.build();
    try {
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
    } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
        UsageTracker.handleException(e);
    }
```

Loading the image from a Service:

```
public static void updateImage(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews, int resourceId, String url) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class));
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(remoteViews, resourceId, appWidgetIds);
}
```

Also, does anyone know if it's normal that indicators and logging don't work for RemoteViews?

Comment: Have you tried using Picasso's `setIndicatorsEnabled` to verify that the images are not being loaded from cache?

Comment: Yes, but there are no indicators appearing in the appwidget. They do work in the app itself. Are they supposed to work in RemoteViews for appwidgets?

Comment: I don't see any reason as to why they shouldn't be.. That being said I've not tested this myself. Maybe it's worth opening an issue if thats not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questing in case anyone stumbles upon the question with a similar problem.

By design an HTTP request is send to the server which responds with a 304 status even if the cache-age is still valid to be able to measure on the server how often an image is displayed. The data usage we were seeing in Android were not images but a lot of headers.